# Add Page Tab dialog: restrict user to choose only one page at a time

Tags: dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Add to Page dialog:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

But I want the user to do just one page at a time, so I can easily walk them through an app customization wizard for each page without them getting confused.

Is there a way to change the dialog to be only single select of page instead of multi select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is: no, there is no way to do it with the dialog. The Facebook add page dialog always returns an array of pages the user added to and there is no option to make it only ask for one page.

Another option is to write our own add page dialog, but this requires the manage_pages extended permission from the user, which would scare them away in our case.

What I ultimately did in the project to solve the problem was to use the add page dialog and accept an array of answers. It stored this array to a session and walked the user through our custom wizard one page at a time, allowing them to customize the second page once they were finished with the first page.

So the flow went like this:

1) Present them the Facebook provided dialog. We added some text telling the user what to expect from the dialog.

2) Save the tabs_added information.

3) For each tab added, create an account in our system for that page, display some information about the page and ask the user for additional customization information about that page.

4) After each one is finished, goto step 3.

It wasn't exactly what we wanted and most users only used one page anyway, but it worked.